# 5000px+ Wide Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm building this website and I have basically two questions about this page:
http://sites.publishyours.com.br/silviamecozzi/pt/obra/deserto_das_palmas.php

On the link you'll see some "will be" images with different sizes and it's legends.
Some of this images will be as wide as 1700px+ and here comes the first problem and question.

Checking the html and css you'll see a div with an id of "gallery" that is holding all the images. It's absolute positioned and I'm setting its width to 4800px (not enough to hold all the images that are all floated to the left. If you change this width to 5000px, it will be enough to hold all the images and everything will be fine as it should be but...

Question 01:
Why do I need to set the div#gallery width? I'll have other sections like that with different images/sizes and I can't preview how wide it will need to be. I just want it to go as wide as it's needed and if I need to add more images later, I want it to push it as wide as needed.

Question 02:
First note how I set the left position of the "gallery" div to -150px.
Well, once I have the first question solved, I will probably set the 'html' tag to { overflow-x: hidden; }. And use a horizontal scroll that will be as wide as the website (+- 920px), right below the images, and I want the images to scroll (with a jQuery scroll) from the 'hidden right' like { left: 0px; } to the 'hidden left' like { left: -3980px; } of the browser and vice-versa, as the user uses the scroll... This scroll will need to calculate the width of the #gallery div and all... Can someone point me to a jQuery plugin that will help me do that? I'm thinking about jscrollpane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) but I really don't know if it will do.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: You can use `pre` or `nowrap` to prevent wrapping. You don't need to set a gallery width as long as your html structure and css are correct.

Question 2: You can use the scrollLeft property in jQuery to bring elements into view. You don't need a plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Tsfv/1

Then use the scrollLeft property to animate the next element into view. This example does not handle border cases, so it will break if you click left/right too many times. It should be easy for you to modify it for your needs though.

css

```
body { white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; }
img { margin: 5px; border: 1px solid black; }
img.active { border-color: orange; }
div{ position: fixed; }​
```

html

```
<div><button id="left"><-</button><button id="right">-></button></div><br /><br />
<img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/500x100/" /><img src="http://placehold.it/750x100/" /><img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/300x100/" /><img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/1000x100/" />
```

jquery

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    var $prev = $('.active').prev();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $prev.addClass('active');   
    $('body').animate( { scrollLeft: $prev.offset().left }, 'slow');
});

$('#right').click(function() {
    var $next = $('.active').next();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $next.addClass('active');   
    $('body').animate( { scrollLeft: $next.offset().left }, 'slow');
});
​
```

Comment: Tks for your time and so helpful answer!
I just solved Q-01 problem using `nowrap;` in my CSS, and I'm here to give this first "feedback".  
Here's a test page to check the results:
[example](http://sites.publishyours.com.br/silviamecozzi/pt/test.html)  
I had to do some tests and here's what I basically had to use:  
`#gallery { white-space: nowrap; }` _div holding all figure tags_  
`figure { display: inline-block; }` _it didn't work with inline_  
Now I have to solve the jQuery part. A horizontal scrollbar will be needed because some imgs will be very wide. A simple click of btn won't do it

Comment: And just to better explain why btns won't do for the imgs nav, I'll use your own [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tsfv/1).
When you get to the 1000px wide img, if the user has a small window, he won't be able to see the right side of the image and when the user clicks the right btn the img just goes so fast that he/she still won't be able to see the img details. That's why a scrollbar is so needed. The user will have the option to see the imgs the way he wants. I could even add the btns later, but the scrollbar is really needed. Any idea? And thanks again!

Comment: Set the image container to 100% with an overflow-x property then? http://jsfiddle.net/3Tsfv/2/

Comment: thanks again! This is "almost" what I need. The only problem is that doing this, the 100% width will be related the same space I have for my website (920px). What I need is an horizontal scrollbar that is 920px wide and I need the images to scroll through 100% width of the browser window.<br />
If the window has 1600px, I need a 920px wide scrollbar and the images running through all the 1600px; That's why I was thinking about a jquery scrollbar plugin. This way, those with big screens would be able to see the bigger imgs using its monitor resolution.  What do you think? Any idea?

Comment: mrtsherman, I almost got what I need... it's really almost finished.
I'm using jQuery UI Slider and I'm grabbing this [example code](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll)
I just don't understand why it's not working yet... Actually it's working but the handler is not 'sliding' inside the 'slider space' I have... I also checked the css to see if it's something invisible/not styled but no... here's the [link](http://sites.publishyours.com.br/silviamecozzi/pt/obra/deserto_das_palmas.php) so you can see how it is now.

Comment: @7th - are you loading a jQuery UI theme? It is meant to be used by one. Only the dark gray bar is the slider portion. The lighter gray it rests in is due to the div with class `slider` that has background color `#C9C9C9`. The slider widget is invisible and not sure why. I suspect if you loaded a jQuery UI theme it would work.

Comment: mrtsherman, you must be right! I'm not loading a UI theme because I thought it was not needed since I want it to look like what you're seen there now (just a gray bar over a light gray bar). I won't work with it anymore today but I'll try to load the UI theme tomorrow and see how it goes with it... for now, I can't thank you enough for your attention! Really!

Comment: mrtsherman, I'm almost there but there's something wrong... If you have the time, would you check my script.js file and try to find what am I doing wrong while trying to calculate my content width? It's returning a 'nonsense' value so I'm doing it manually. But I need it to be calculated automatically or I'll have problems with the size of the content on the other pages =(
Thanks again! Really!

Comment: Hey sorry, don't have time right now. You should post into a new SO question. I'm sure someone will know what to do.

Comment: Thanks mrtsherman! I'll do that... don't worry.
I just find out that it works in Firefox and IE and it seems to be a Chrome/webkit bug calculating outerWidth of objects... 
Again, thanks for your time and help! It's much appreciated!